# Dynamically attaching and removing event listeners in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

the remove event listener does not seem to work for my code; I have created a small code sandbox that tries to replicate the scenario am facing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-browser-zznsj

so basically when `input is not listening`, the input event listener should be detached from the input tag and any text written in the tag should not be written to the message state variable and thus  further changes to the input tag input value should not show up on the ui, this is however not how the code behaves, and the reason i think it behaves like that is that it does not properly detach the event listener

Comment: Put your `if (listening) { ... }` inside your callback function. Only do something if the listening value is TRUE

Comment: @Weedoze yeap that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario because you are using input tag.
Use `change` event listener.

Check on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Or as you are using React my preferred way would be:

1 - Don't use `useEffect` hook.

2 - Put a condition in your `callback`:

```
function callback(event) {
    if (listening) {
      setMessage(event.target.value);
    }
    return;
  }
```

3 - In JSX code just do this.

```
 <input type="text" id="input" onChange={callback}/>
```

Comment: For the `callback` function, it is clearer if you say `if(listening) return;` to avoid indentation

Comment: @Praveen Question, what if you want to add the event listener to the window, how would you advise i do that?

Comment: Hey, @Pnet,
For that, `useEffect` if you are using hook i.e

`
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListerner('scroll', scrollCb);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListerner('scroll', scrollCb);
  }
})
`
and `componentDidMount` for adding event listener and `componentWillUnmount` for removing the event listener is the best place.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to attach 'input' event listener. There is no event listener like this. Try using 'keypress' , 'keydown' etc. It is working fine.
Check the code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-bird-4b09c

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: My add event listener is clearly working using the `input` as an event, from the sandbox in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal approach. But You can replace the input element itself and all listeners will get de-registered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-field-6b4fr

```
 var old_element = document.querySelector("#input");
      var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
      old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
```

Comment: Am afraid this does not quite work for my actual use case, but thanks.